# 403 Forbidden message with Apache www directory inside of home

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp

On my Ubuntu server, I've changed my /var/www directory to a subfolder inside of my home directory, and I'm now getting 403 "Forbidden" errors in my browser. I've read through a lot of similar questions, but none of the answers have worked for me. These are the steps I've followed:

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, I changed

```
<Directory /home/var/www>
```

To:

```
<Directory /home/bob/Dropbox/Uniserver/www>
```

I did the same thing in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

To:

```
DocumentRoot /home/bob/Dropbox/UniServer/www
```

(Only for troubleshooting), I ran:

```
chmod 777 -R /home/bob/Dropbox/UniServer/www
```

I also ran:

```
chown -R www-data /home/bob/Dropbox/UniServer/www
```

Also for troubleshooting, I ran the same command for my entire home directory. I restarted Apache a million times:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But typing 'localhost' into my browser still returns a 403 "Forbidden" error. Any ideas?

Comment: I know you said this is just for troubleshooting, but you never want, or need, to give world-write access to your web folder, and you want to avoid giving write access to the `www-data` user/group to anything.  Read-only access is enough, and is much preferred for security reasons.  Sorry this doesn't answer your question though.

Comment: Can you find the relevant lines from `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (hope I'm remembering correctly) when this 403 forbidden error occurs?  You may need to use sudo to even look in that log directory.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo -u www-data namei -l /home/bob/Dropbox/UniServer/www`?

Comment: Did you download apache, MYSQL and PHP seperatly? Or did you get a stack (e.g. XAMPP)?